# Snap geometry in QGIS

Tags: qgis, geometry, snapping

I have a problem, but I didn't find usable solution. I created a line shape as a reference/guideline and made grid with grass v.mkgrid and I should correctly fit the grid onto the line.
[image]

It isn't possible to fitted precision with manual method, and QGIS Geometry snapping didn't work correctly.I approached the line with move and rotation, the distance within 5 meter

[image]

If I used geometry snapper, the tool modified shape and size of polygon, connected to line.
Other situation, if line was within the grid, the tool worked as clip.

Somebody knows such QGIS tool/plugin  what solving this problem?

---

There is nothing logic between layers, line attributes contains just one id, grid contains mkgrid generated data

I tried snap geometry to layer, the results was wrong, the tool stretched the cells to the line, modified  first column's size and because the grid wasn't parallel to line formed the cells into trapeze

Comment: Is there any logic or banding `"id"`s between grids and lines?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using a rectangle (make it a separate layer) instead of a line and then using 'Create grid' algorithm with rectangle layer as the grid extent. That way the grid will fit into the rectangle.